# I want to add foreign key to my second table (sports) for column AdmNo

Tags: mysql

> mysql> desc students;

```
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| AdmNo   | int(5)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Name    | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Class   | int(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Sec     | char(1)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| RNo     | int(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Address | varchar(35) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Phone   | int(9)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

> mysql> desc sports;

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| AdmNo     | int(5)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Game      | varchar(35) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| CoachName | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Grade     | char(1)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

I want to add Foreign Key to my second table `(sports)` for column `AdmNo`.

Comment: Is `AdmNo` a pk? For which table?

Comment: -1 because quite frankly: RTFM + the documentation page actually is the first hit in google anyway => http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
ALTER TABLE sports
ADD FOREIGN KEY (AdmNo)
REFERENCES students(AdmNo)
```

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE students
ADD FOREIGN KEY (AdmNo)
REFERENCES sports(AdmNo)